# SDWebImage giving nil with URL

Tags: ios, swift3, sdwebimage

I've a string in which I've comma separated links of images. Here is how I'm splitting it into an array: `let imagesLinks = imageLins.components(separatedBy: ",")`. Then I've used for loop to get one link, download the image and storing it in a `UIImage` array in this way:

```
for imag in imagesLinks
        {
            let img = UIImageView()

            print("\(baseReportImageURL)\(imag)")

            img.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(baseReportImageURL)\(imag)"), placeholderImage: nil)
            imagesArray.append(img.image!)
        }
```

The print statement is giving me the correct URL which when I open on browser downloads the image. The problem is on the line where I'm appending the array i.e. `imagesArray.append(img.image!)`. I get:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So what would be the correct solution for this?

**UPDATE**

My question is different because I'm using `SDWebImage` and when I use completion block there is a strange behaviour of the app:

```
img.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: nil,options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                imagesArray.append(image!)
                self.photoCollection.reloadData()
            })
```

So it keeps on rotating the activity indicator and when I go back and push the view again it load the images instantly. So I think that the completion block is not called when the image is downloaded but why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if url image exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962938/check-if-url-image-exist)

Comment: Make sure your `imageLinks` doesn't have empty links.

Comment: @Chaudhry Talha  You Get array of Images after Update?

Comment: Array of images is init at a global level. I've added a breakpoint and I'm sure now it's now going in the completion block.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not the proper way to get downloaded images (set images to an UIImageView and then get the images from there).

You should use the image downloader, provided by SDWebImage:

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: <YOUR_URL>, options: [], progress: { (received, expected, nil) in
            print(received,expected)
        }, completed: { (image, data, error, true) in
            yourArray.append(image)
        })
```

If you have indexes, you can update the current row in the `tableview` every time when an image downloaded, or just `reload()` the whole, but I recommend the first.

Answer (score 0):

It is because

```
  imagesArray.append(img.image!)
```

Image take some times for downloading. When you do `imagesArray.append(img.image!)` at that time it is possible that your image is not set to your imageview and that means you are trying to add `nil` in your `imageArray`!

Second thing why are you storing image in an array ? You have array of `urls` and you are using `SDWebImage` then every time when you want to display image use `SDWebImage`. No need to store in array!

And if you want images in array anyhow than use `NSUrlSession` asynchronous requests with completion handlers and from completion handler add image to your array!

Comment: I've a comma separated string with image URL's and SDWebImage completion block is not working for me somehow.  Kindly see if you can add to what I've added in the update section of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Append the image into the images array in the `sd_setImage` completion block.
The image is not yet downloaded when you are trying to add it into the array, and check if the image is not equal nil before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Block For Image Download After download Perform Operation(append Image)

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
 // Perform operation.
//append Image Here
})
```

Comment: there is a strange behaviour. Kindly see my updated question.